# what is the difference between Pane and stackPane in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I was learning javafx and came across these two statements which I don't know their difference.

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
```

and

```
StackPane pane = new StackPane();
```

Can somebody enlighten me about the difference and when to use which?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are layouts but the `Pane` is the basis of all the other layouts, the difference is that the Pane offers a free positioning of nodes, and The `StackPane` (and other Node with the suffix Pane called **Built-in Layout**) in return, follow their own logic (Positions/Constraints...). The 'StackPane' for example lays out its children in a back-to-front stack [StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html). This is only superficial and limited information, here's a good tutorial : [Layout in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG)

Comment: i see that when you use stackpane the shapes do not follow the co-ordinate system. instead they position them selves on their own no matter which location i specify @BoHalim

Comment: Technically everything that extends Pane preserves the children Z order. I've done this without a StackPane using a Pane or AnchorPane many times. So it's just the layout stuff that's really different (i.e. the methods in StackPane's Javadoc). Pane's Javadoc also mentions StackPane: "Note: if an application needs children to be kept aligned within a parent (centered, positioned at top-left, etc), it should use a StackPane instead."

Answer (score 4):

The difference between both layouts is positioning of the children and the resizing of resizeable children.

`Pane` does not do any positioning. The child's `layoutX` and `layoutY` are left unmodified. Furthermore resizeable children are resized to their preferred sizes.

`StackPane` determines the position of children based on the alignment set for the child itself or the one set for the `StackPane` itself, if no position is set for the child. Resizable children are resized to a size that fits the `StackPane`'s size best (still taking into account max size). Both can be modified by a margin set for individual children...