# JavaFX StackPane showing incorrect (X,Y) Coordination

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, coordinates

I am trying to print all the nodes in the StackPane.
I am required to get X,Y coordinates and height and width of the nodes (all Rectangls).
However, it shows (0,0) for the X,Y coordinates even though I have specifically chosen other than it.

Code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle();
    rec1.setTranslateX(230);
    rec1.setTranslateY(230);
    rec1.setWidth(50);
    rec1.setHeight(50);

    Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle();
    rec2.setTranslateX(150);
    rec2.setTranslateY(150);
    rec2.setWidth(75);
    rec2.setHeight(75);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(rec1);
    root.getChildren().add(rec2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Shapes");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    System.out.println(root.getChildren());
}
```

Output:

`[Rectangle[x=0.0, y=0.0, width=50.0, height=50.0, fill=0x000000ff], Rectangle[x=0.0, y=0.0, width=75.0, height=75.0, fill=0x000000ff]]`

As you can see from the output above. The height and width works but the X and Y layout/translation is not showing. I have also used:  `rec1.setLayoutX(230)` but this did not change anything.

What is the problem?
And how can I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: See what happens if you use `Pane` as your root node instead of `StackPane`.

Comment: @Sedrick Yeah I tried using; Pane, GridPane and AnchorPane but it did not change anything when printing the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To printout information other than included in `Node.toSring` tailor the printout to your needs. For example:

```
print(root.getChildren());
private void print(ObservableList<Node> children) {
        for(Node child: children){
            double width = child.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
            Object height = child.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
            double x = child.getTranslateX();
            double y = child.getTranslateY();
            System.out.println("trans x - y: " + x + " - "+y  + " width - height: " + width +" - "+ height);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try `rec1.setX(100)` it will show it as [Rectangle[x=100.0, y=0.0].
Same for `rec1.setY()`. Have a look on the docs about [setX()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html#setX-double-), [setTranslateX()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setTranslateX-double-), [setLayoutX()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutX-double-).

Comment: Although when I used  `rec1.setX(100)` it showed the correct set X and Y coordinates when printing. However, in the actual scene, the Rectangles were all in the middle of this scene and not placed correctly. So it cause more problems than it solved. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: _"the Rectangles were all in the middle"_ sounds right as _"StackPane lays out its children in a back-to-front stack."_ Is [StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) the appropriate pane layout you wish to use? Have a look at this answer about [the difference of Pane and StackPane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41202628/11072062)